# Incompatible Spring dependencies (NoSuchMethodError when AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource constructor is called)

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-commons, spring-boot-starter

I can't start my Spring Boot application anymore after adding persistence. The error is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/type/AnnotationMetadata;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistry;)V
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport$1.<init>(AbstractRepositoryConfigurationSourceSupport.java:68) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
```

I tracked this down to the changes in *spring-data-commons* where *AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource* resides and an additional constructor argument was added in version 1.13.5, and version 1.13.7 with the same constructor signature should be used by *spring-boot-starter-data-jpa* in version 1.5.7. And we only use Spring Boot dependencies with version number 1.5.7.

So then I built the dependency tree and strangely found *spring-data-commons* in version 1.13.4, not 1.13.7 (third to last line):

```
...(snippet)
[INFO] +- com.name.project:project-subproject8:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.15:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.15:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.9.RELEASE:compile
...
```

Going up the tree you can see that *spring-data-jpa* is included in version 1.11.4, whereas, according to [Spring Boot Dependency Appendix](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.7.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html), it should be version 1.11.7. This seems to cause the error. But we don't depend on *spring-data-jpa* directly via our pom files.

So I don't know how this older version got into the dependency tree.
The pom of *spring-boot-starter-data-jpa* doesn't indicate any version numbers.

Comment: Have you already tried to fix this with exclusions or with dependency management ?

Comment: Sure, exclusions & explicitly adding the required artifact versions helps. 
But that is only fighting the symptoms.

Comment: can you attach depency parts of your pom ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and yeah it is SOLVED now!!!
You can always exclude particular inner dependency from the outer dependency.  You have already given hint to solve this issue. 
The root cause is that you most likely have compiled a class against a different version of the class that is missing a method, than the one you are using when running it. 
I switched to 1.5.7 version of spring boot, so i just needed to add jpa dependency compatible with spring boot 1.5.7 version. Why jpa dependency because - org.springframework.data.repository.config.AnnotationRepositoryConfigurationSource is in the spring data package. And it worked